# standard practice for running co-dependent scripts/apps

Tags: c#, sql, ssis, etl

I am in need of your guidance on how to properly set this project up. I am pulling data from a few different sources using a few tools that I wrote, a few tools that I downloaded, and my SSIS packages.

Here is the timeline of what is supposed to occur:

> 1. files are grabbed either from ftp/sftp site or from a windows directory
> 2. certain files need to be decrypted with PGP
> 3. all source files are moved into their designated source file locations
> 4. SSIS packages run to read and load all the data and perform manipulation

**question:** how do i make sure that these separate applications don't run into each other? yes, i can set them all to be task scheduled at different times, but what if the previous application got stuck somewhere? is there a best practice way to run applications that are co-dependent and must not overlap?

Comment: You use a Job-Scheduling facility and make them sequential steps in the same job.

Comment: excellent - can you recommend one?

Comment: Um, SQL Server has one built-in, it's called the SQL Agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Scheduling**

For scheduling use Sql Server Agent.

Here is an [article to get you started](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1568-how-to-use-sql-server-agent/)

**Simple multi-step jobs**

If the relationship between the different steps of your job is very simple (a then b then c, etc) you can use SQL server agent to handle that as well.

Here is [an article](http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/ss/sql_server_agent.htm) which shows how to use more than one step within the same sql server agent job. See especially pages 4 & 5.

**More complex jobs**

If your job gets at all complicated in terms of the relationships between the different things that need to be run I recommend using a master SSIS package which itself can call other SSIS packages. You still use Sql Server agent for scheduling. In that case the agent job just kicks off the master package.

The master package typically calls child packages with the Execute Package task. That process has worked fine for my team. That said, you may want the additional flexibility of using a script task. In that case see [this article.](http://www.duncansutcliffe.com/?p=38)